# Extending background colour to the edges in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I am trying to **colour the background** of just a **part of a page** from **edge to edge**. MS Word has a feature for colouring the entire background of the document via the "Design" menu, but I only want a specific part of the page coloured.

By adding a shadow/background colour to the lines, the margins are still white:

[image]

Adjusting the pins in the top ruler-bar doesn't work since the text will follow along:

[image]
[image]

I want the text to stay where it is an obey the margins that are already set. But I want the background colour to extend all the way to the edge left and right. I have not been able to google my way to a solution. How can this be done?

I use Microsoft Word 360.

Comment: As far as I know, this is not feasible. The background size of the paragraph is related to the size of the paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

You could move the left and right paragraph INDENT to the edges. That would make typing harder, though.

You could try putting a shaded textbox behind your text. Anchor the textbox to the paragraph.

[image: screenshot]

Here is a [temporary link to the document](https://www.dropbox.com/s/efx12mgxf7erssz/deleteme%20textbox%20behind%202021-06-26.docx?dl=0) used for this screenshot.

Comment: Hi Charles. Could you elaborate on how you would anchor the textbox to the paragraph? How do you do this?

Comment: You need to turn on display of anchors. Then you can move the anchor to the paragraph. See the screenshot and temporary link added to my answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Alright, thanks, this is doable. With this method I can have a none flexible background colour from edge to edge. Meaning, this box won't stretch automatically to contain the text when more lines are added. And it can't span two pages, so I will have to manually fix such situations in my document.

Comment: You are correct that it is a clumsy workaround, but does work.